# MongoDB object instance

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, database

I don't have any prior experience with database, but I have to use it for a app that I'm building, and I choose MongoDB.

Now everything is working, but I'm creating a new Mongo object every time I have to make an request to the database, and I understand that's wrong.

So I want ask and learn what is the correct way to do this, I have some code like the following in a class called `MongoDbConnnection`:

```
public class MongoDbConnection {
    private static Mongo _mongo;
        public static Mongo getMongo()
        {
            if (_mongo == null) {
            try {
                    _mongo = new Mongo();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    _mongo = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MongoException e) {
                    _mongo = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return _mongo;
    }
}
```

So that every time I need to do a query, I do `Mongo m = MongoDbConnnection.getMongo();` and proceed forward.

Is this correct?

I also confuse about when to close the connection, as I have another class that extends `HttpServlet` and will respond GET, every time someone request that url I will have to query the database and return the information. If I close right after I respond to one request, what if other people request it again right after that. Then I have to create a new Mongo object again?

In other words, I know Mongo instance maintain a connection poll, so when I call m.close(), am I just replace the connection I used, or am I setting object `m` to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are mostly getting a connection from the pool of connection maintained for you with:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo();
DB db = m.getDB( "mydb" );
```

You only need one Mongo object, and it is thread safe.

I have not looked into the implementation in details, but you have to call

```
db.close() from your code.
```

This will simply returns the connection to the pool and not close it. 
If you forget to do it, I suppose it is going to take time, before the Mongo object realize the connection is not used anymore.